# Concatenate variable number of element string values via XPath 1.0?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I'm trying to use XPath 1.0 to select all of the text within these `li` elements, except for the last one with `class="detailCrumb"`.

I'd like my result to look like:

```
Home Photography Memory Cards &amp; Accessories Memory Cards
```

***These breadcrumbs will be dynamic based on the level of the site I'm at, so I can't specify positional requests***, such as `li[4]`. How can I achieve this?

```
<div class="breadcrums-cont">
    <ul id="breadcrumbs" ">
        <li class="first">Home</li>
        <li>Photography</li>
        <li>Memory Cards &amp; Accessories</li> 
        <li>Memory Cards</li>
        <li class="detailCrumb">SanDisk Extreme Pro</li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To exept li tags with class "detailCrumb", use not() function

```
//ul[@id="breadcrumbs"]/li[not(@class="detailCrumb")]
```

Comment: I tried this, but it only returns the first li (Home).

Comment: It returns node list. If you use xpath 1.0, you can concatenate them only by another instrument. for example, using your programming language

Comment: I'm using a web scraping tool that uses XPath 1.0, so I don't have have the ability to edit the underlying code I'm scraping from.

Comment: i'm sure in Xpath, but know nothing about web scraping tool  :(

Answer (score 1):

### XPath 1.0

The *usual* answer is that you can concatenate a *fixed* number of items:

```
concat(//ul[@id="breadcrumbs"]/li[not(@class="detailCrumb")][1], ' ',
       //ul[@id="breadcrumbs"]/li[not(@class="detailCrumb")][2], ' ',
       //ul[@id="breadcrumbs"]/li[not(@class="detailCrumb")][3])
```

To concatenate a *variable* number of items, [as @splash58 has said (+1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718974/xpath-1-0-select-all-li-elements-except-one-based-on-class/47725129#comment82398641_47719121), you'll have to use string concatenation facilities of the language calling XPath – XPath 1.0 alone cannot do it.

***However, if you start with the string value of the entire list and then take away the unwanted string,***

```
normalize-space(
   substring-before(//ul[@id="breadcrumbs"],
                    //ul[@id="breadcrumbs"]/li[@class="detailCrumb"]))
```

***then you can achieve your requested result:***

```
Home Photography Memory Cards & Accessories Memory Cards
```

### XPath 2.0

You can join a *variable* number of items in XPath via `string-join()`:

```
string-join(//ul[@id="breadcrumbs"]/li[not(@class="detailCrumb")], ' ')
```

returns

```
Home Photography Memory Cards & Accessories Memory Cards
```

as requested.